# .htaccesss RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d does not work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I want to  install WordPress in subdirectory and remove index.php in permalinks. 
The server is IIS 6.0, support rewrite.
My webserver has the following directories:

> webroot
>   --wp [wordpress folder]

**webroot/.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?a.luckyet\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?a.luckyet\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp/
```

**webroot/wp/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,PT,L] #3
```

It works when I visit *a.luckyet.com* and *a.luckyet.com/hello-world.html*
But it does not work when I visit *a.luckyet.com/wp-login.php* or *a.luckyet.com/wp-admin*

The #3 works fine, but #1 and #2 can not work properly. Then I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930519/write-an-htaccess-file-without-request-filename) and change the content of **webroot/wp/.htaccess** to:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

It still does not take effect. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

ISAPI_Rewrite version is 3.0.

All code in **webroot/.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?a.luckyet\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?a.luckyet\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp/
```

All code in **webroot/wp/.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on 
# For file-based wordpress content (i.e. theme), admin, etc.
RewriteRule wp-(.*) wp-$1 [L]
# For normal wordpress content, via index.php
RewriteRule ^/$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #2
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Wordpress permalink is:

```
/%postname%.html
```

Thus, Wordpress can work fine when visit http://a.luckyet.com/ or http://a.luckyet.com/hello-world.html

**Question:**

If there is a real file like a.html in *webroot/wp/*, like *webroot/wp/a.html*, wordpress 404 error will be reported when visit *http://a.luckyet.com/a.html*, . How can I fixed this?

Comment: It should be `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f` or `!-d`. What ISAPI_Rewrite version are you using?

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work. I also do not know the ISAPI_Rewrite version, it is a virtual host I bought.

Comment: I update the question, are thera any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems all [ISAPI 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/compatibility.htm) server variables and directives in your question are Apache compatible, so compatibility is not the problem. I see several blocks of rules in the .htacces file at *wp* directory, but there is no indication of the position of each one inside the file. Maybe you could copy+paste into your question the complete .htaccess file content instead of the actual blocks, to better understand the whole code.

Comment: I update it, thanks for your help!

Comment: If you want to load an existing file at system path `webroot/wp/a.html`, why the request is `http://a.luckyet.com/a.html`? Isn't `/webroot` the directory where DocumentRoot is pointing to? If so, the request should be `http://a.luckyet.com/wp/a.html`

Comment: With the `webroot/.htaccess`, `a.luckyet.com` pointing to `webroot/wp/` subdirectory, the request `http://a.luckyet.com` is access `webroot/wp/`. So I want to use `http://a.luckyet.com/a.html` to access `webroot/wp/a.html`.

Comment: I want to achieve this function: 
to cache some articles. when I wrote an article with permalink `http://a.luckyet.com/hello-world.html`, then cache a html file `webroot/wp/hello-world.html`. I want to make the request `http://a.luckyet.com/hello-world.html` to access the html file `webroot/wp/hello-world.html`, no need to generate it with wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You're dynamically rewriting the URLs with the .htaccess file and WordPress settings to tack on the .html extension - any files that are "real-life" .html files are being handled upstream by the IIS Handler Mappings.

You'll have to update your Handler Mappings in IIS for .html files especially to direct the requests directly to the physical file.